# SharePoint and SalesForce.com Chatter communication

Tags: 2007, integration

I need to retrieve updates in a particular Chatter Group to display them in a SharePoint WebPart. It will be just one-way communication from Chatter to SharePoint. Can anybody guide me about:

- How to communicate with Chatter through .NET?
- How credentials can be transmitted to avoid login prompts?
- Any special development tool/utilities/Assemblies needed to be installed on my development machine to make life easier?
- Where can I find the documentation for Chatter API?
- Any licensing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AvePoint offers a product that integrates salesforce and sharepoint, and are the only ones who do so as far as I'm aware